# How to match numbers between X and Y with regexp?

Tags: regex

I would like to match with RegExp a number between X and Y. Is that possible?

([0-9]+) will match any number, how could I do to match a number between, for instance, 110 and 2234?

Comment: Yes it is possible. So is cutting your toenails with a running chainsaw. Neither are very good ideas.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

According to [Generate a Regular Expression to Match an Arbitrary Numeric Range](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/534137/), and after generating such a regex for your example at [Regex_For_Range](https://web.archive.org/web/20151029043426/http://utilitymill.com/utility/Regex_For_Range):

```
\b0*(1[1-9][0-9]|[2-9][0-9]{2}|1[0-9]{3}|2[01][0-9]{2}|22[0-2][0-9]|223[0-4])\b
```

would do the trick.

The process would be (still following that Regex generator):

> First, break into equal length ranges:

```
110 - 999
1000 - 2234
```

> Second, break into ranges that yield simple regexes:

```
110 - 199
200 - 999
1000 - 1999
2000 - 2199
2200 - 2229
2230 - 2234
```

> Turn each range into a regex:

```
1[1-9][0-9]
[2-9][0-9]{2}
1[0-9]{3}
2[01][0-9]{2}
22[0-2][0-9]
223[0-4]
```

> Collapse adjacent powers of 10:
>       1[1-9][0-9]
>       [2-9][0-9]{2}
>       1[0-9]{3}
>       2[01][0-9]{2}
>       22[0-2][0-9]
>       223[0-4]
>
> Combining the regexes above yields:

```
0*(1[1-9][0-9]|[2-9][0-9]{2}|1[0-9]{3}|2[01][0-9]{2}|22[0-2][0-9]|223[0-4])
```

> Next we'll try factoring out common prefixes using a tree:
>   Parse into tree based on regex prefixes:

```
. 1 [1-9] [0-9]
+ [0-9]{3}
+ [2-9] [0-9]{2}
+ 2 [01] [0-9]{2}
+ 2 [0-2] [0-9]
+ 3 [0-4]
```

> Turning the parse tree into a regex yields:

```
0*(1([1-9][0-9]|[0-9]{3})|[2-9][0-9]{2}|2([01][0-9]{2}|2([0-2][0-9]|3[0-4])))
```

> We choose the shorter one as our result.

```
\b0*(1[1-9][0-9]|[2-9][0-9]{2}|1[0-9]{3}|2[01][0-9]{2}|22[0-2][0-9]|223[0-4])\b
```

Comment: A C#/VB.NET/PHP or any other language except the one I don't know would be great. ;)

Comment: didn't edit the above in time, I meant to say the valid numbers padded with leading 0's: 0110, 00110, 000110...

Comment: the link request credencials for see

Comment: @Doberon Yes, thank you. I have restored the link, but I don't think the online script is still working.

Answer (score 29):

This is not the sort of thing regexes excel at.  You will probably find it easier to ensure that you have the right number of digits `/^([0-9]{3,4})$/` and then do further checks against the capture.

Answer (score 10):

## • Numeric range regex generator

Since online number range regex generator services often become unavailable after some period of time ([this one](https://www.richie-bendall.ml/ros-regex-numeric-range-generator/) is still alive at the time of writing the post), I think it would be nice to have it here.

**How-to**:

- Scroll to the bottom of this answer
- Click **`Run code snippet`**
- Make sure you type the minimum and maximum threshold values in the text input fields, mark all the options you need below and hit <kbd>**Generate**</kbd> button:

```js
!function(e){if("object"==typeof exports&&"undefined"!=typeof module)module.exports=e();else if("function"==typeof define&&define.amd)define([],e);else{("undefined"!=typeof window?window:"undefined"!=typeof global?global:"undefined"!=typeof self?self:this).toRegexRange=e()}}(function(){return function(){return function e(t,n,r){function i(u,a){if(!n[u]){if(!t[u]){var s="function"==typeof require&&require;if(!a&&s)return s(u,!0);if(o)return o(u,!0);var c=new Error("Cannot find module '"+u+"'");throw c.code="MODULE_NOT_FOUND",c}var f=n[u]={exports:{}};t[u][0].call(f.exports,function(e){return i(t[u][1][e]||e)},f,f.exports,e,t,n,r)}return n[u].exports}for(var o="function"==typeof require&&require,u=0;u<r.length;u++)i(r[u]);return i}}()({1:[function(e,t,n){"use strict";const r=e("is-number"),i=(e,t,n)=>{if(!1===r(e))throw new TypeError("toRegexRange: expected the first argument to be a number");if(void 0===t||e===t)return String(e);if(!1===r(t))throw new TypeError("toRegexRange: expected the second argument to be a number.");let o={relaxZeros:!0,...n};"boolean"==typeof o.strictZeros&&(o.relaxZeros=!1===o.strictZeros);let s=e+":"+t+"="+String(o.relaxZeros)+String(o.shorthand)+String(o.capture)+String(o.wrap);if(i.cache.hasOwnProperty(s))return i.cache[s].result;let c=Math.min(e,t),f=Math.max(e,t);if(1===Math.abs(c-f)){let n=e+"|"+t;return o.capture?`(${n})`:!1===o.wrap?n:`(?:${n})`}let l=h(e)||h(t),d={min:e,max:t,a:c,b:f},p=[],g=[];if(l&&(d.isPadded=l,d.maxLen=String(d.max).length),c<0){g=u(f<0?Math.abs(f):1,Math.abs(c),d,o),c=d.a=0}return f>=0&&(p=u(c,f,d,o)),d.negatives=g,d.positives=p,d.result=function(e,t,n){let r=a(e,t,"-",!1,n)||[],i=a(t,e,"",!1,n)||[],o=a(e,t,"-?",!0,n)||[];return r.concat(o).concat(i).join("|")}(g,p,o),!0===o.capture?d.result=`(${d.result})`:!1!==o.wrap&&p.length+g.length>1&&(d.result=`(?:${d.result})`),i.cache[s]=d,d.result};function o(e,t,n){if(e===t)return{pattern:e,count:[],digits:0};let r=function(e,t){let n=[];for(let r=0;r<e.length;r++)n.push([e[r],t[r]]);return n}(e,t),i=r.length,o="",u=0;for(let e=0;e<i;e++){let[t,i]=r[e];t===i?o+=t:"0"!==t||"9"!==i?o+=p(t,i,n):u++}return u&&(o+=!0===n.shorthand?"\\d":"[0-9]"),{pattern:o,count:[u],digits:i}}function u(e,t,n,r){let i,u=function(e,t){let n=1,r=1,i=f(e,n),o=new Set([t]);for(;e<=i&&i<=t;)o.add(i),i=f(e,n+=1);for(i=l(t+1,r)-1;e<i&&i<=t;)o.add(i),i=l(t+1,r+=1)-1;return(o=[...o]).sort(s),o}(e,t),a=[],c=e;for(let e=0;e<u.length;e++){let t=u[e],s=o(String(c),String(t),r),f="";n.isPadded||!i||i.pattern!==s.pattern?(n.isPadded&&(f=g(t,n,r)),s.string=f+s.pattern+d(s.count),a.push(s),c=t+1,i=s):(i.count.length>1&&i.count.pop(),i.count.push(s.count[0]),i.string=i.pattern+d(i.count),c=t+1)}return a}function a(e,t,n,r,i){let o=[];for(let i of e){let{string:e}=i;r||c(t,"string",e)||o.push(n+e),r&&c(t,"string",e)&&o.push(n+e)}return o}function s(e,t){return e>t?1:t>e?-1:0}function c(e,t,n){return e.some(e=>e[t]===n)}function f(e,t){return Number(String(e).slice(0,-t)+"9".repeat(t))}function l(e,t){return e-e%Math.pow(10,t)}function d(e){let[t=0,n=""]=e;return n||t>1?`{${t+(n?","+n:"")}}`:""}function p(e,t,n){return`[${e}${t-e==1?"":"-"}${t}]`}function h(e){return/^-?(0+)\d/.test(e)}function g(e,t,n){if(!t.isPadded)return e;let r=Math.abs(t.maxLen-String(e).length),i=!1!==n.relaxZeros;switch(r){case 0:return"";case 1:return i?"0?":"0";case 2:return i?"0{0,2}":"00";default:return i?`0{0,${r}}`:`0{${r}}`}}i.cache={},i.clearCache=(()=>i.cache={}),t.exports=i},{"is-number":2}],2:[function(e,t,n){"use strict";t.exports=function(e){return"number"==typeof e?e-e==0:"string"==typeof e&&""!==e.trim()&&(Number.isFinite?Number.isFinite(+e):isFinite(+e))}},{}]},{},[1])(1)});


$( document ).ready( function() {
  $( "#rangeLeft, #rangeRight" ).keydown( function() {
    clearDisplay();
  } );
  $('#wholestring').click(function() {
        $('#wholestring').attr('checked', 'checked');
        $('#wb').attr('checked', false);
        $('#dgtb').attr('checked', false);
        $('#whtb').attr('checked', false);
    })
  $('#wb').click(function() {
        $('#wb').attr('checked', 'checked');
        $('#wholestring').attr('checked', false);
        $('#dgtb').attr('checked', false);
        $('#whtb').attr('checked', false);
    })
  $('#dgtb').click(function() {
        $('#dgtb').attr('checked', 'checked');
        $('#wb').attr('checked', false);
        $('#wholestring').attr('checked', false);
        $('#whtb').attr('checked', false);
    })
  $('#whtb').click(function() {
        $('#whtb').attr('checked', 'checked');
        $('#wb').attr('checked', false);
        $('#dgtb').attr('checked', false);
        $('#wholestring').attr('checked', false);
    })
  $( "#run" ).click( function() {
    clearDisplay();
    var rangeLeft = $( "#rangeLeft" ).val();
    var rangeRight = $( "#rangeRight" ).val();
    if ( ! checkRanges( rangeLeft,  rangeRight ) ) return;
    let source = toRegexRange(rangeLeft, rangeRight);
    
    if ($('#frac').is(':checked')) {
        source = source + '(?:\\.\\d+)?';
    }
    if ($('#allowzero').is(':checked')) {
        source = "0*" + source;
    }
    if ($('#neg').is(':checked')) {
        source = "-?" + source;
    }
    if ( $('#wholestring').is(':checked')) {
        source = '^' + source + '$';
    } else if ( $('#wb').is(':checked')) {
        source = '\\b' + source + '\\b';
    } else if ( $('#whtb').is(':checked')) {
        source = '(?<!\\S)' + source + '(?!\\S)';
    } else if ( $('#dgtb').is(':checked')) {
        source = '(?<!\\d)' + source + '(?!\\d)';
    }
    $( "#result" ).append( "<B>" + source.replace(/&/g,'&amp;').replace(/</g,'&lt;').replace(/>/g,'&gt;') + "</B><BR/>" );
  } );
} );

function checkRanges( rangeLeft, rangeRight ) {
  if ( /\D/.test( rangeLeft ) || /\D/.test( rangeRight ) ) {
    $( "#result" ).append( "Type two numbers<BR/>" );
    return false;
  }
  rangeLeft = parseInt( rangeLeft );
  rangeRight = parseInt( rangeRight );
  if ( isNaN( rangeLeft ) || isNaN( rangeRight ) ) $( "#result" ).append( "Range boundaries are not specified<BR/>" );
  if ( rangeLeft < 0 ) $( "#result" ).append( "Left boundary is less than 0<BR/>" );
  if ( rangeRight < 0 ) $( "#result" ).append( "Right boundary is less than 0<BR/>" );
  if ( rangeLeft > rangeRight ) $( "#result" ).append( "Left boundary is greater than the right boundary<BR/>" );
  return( !(
    rangeLeft < 0 ||
    rangeRight < 0 ||
    rangeLeft > rangeRight ||
    isNaN( rangeLeft ) ||
    isNaN( rangeRight )
  ) );
}

function clearDisplay() {
  $( "#result" ).html( "" );
  $( "#test" ).hide();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <p>Type in minimum and maximum values and click <i>Generate</i>.</p>
    <INPUT id="rangeLeft" value=1 /> - <INPUT id="rangeRight" value=365 />
    <BR/>
    <BUTTON id="run">Generate</BUTTON>
    <pre><code id="result" /></pre>
    <div>
       <label><input type="checkbox" id="wholestring"/>Match whole string</label> <br/>
       <label><input type="checkbox" id="wb"/>Match within word boundaries</label><br/>
       <label><input type="checkbox" id="dgtb"/>Match when not enclosed with digits</label><br/>
       <label><input type="checkbox" id="whtb"/>Match when enclosed with whitespaces or start/end of string</label><br/>
       <label><input type="checkbox" id="allowzero"/>Allow leading zeros</label><br/>
       <label><input type="checkbox" id="neg"/>Optionally match negative numbers</label><br/>
       <label><input type="checkbox" id="frac"/>Optionally match fractional digits (floats)</label><br/>
    </div>
```

Most of the JavaScript code here is borrowed from [Алгоритм для преобразования диапазона номеров в регулярное выражение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/245209) and [to-regex-range](https://www.npmjs.com/package/to-regex-range) npm library.

Comment: If anyone does not understand how to use the above snippet please see my [YT video instruction](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hSGq5rHIINs).

Comment: And apologies to anyone who is behind a company's firewall and getting a " 
Bitdefender Endpoint Security Tools blocked this page" notificiation :( I do not know why they consider it hacking, all the source is here, you can check and see there is nothing that hacks anything. It is a life-hack, yes :)

Answer (score 7):

You can put the regexes for the following ranges together:

```
1[1-9]\d  = 110-199
[2-9]\d\d = 200-999
1\d\d\d   = 1000-1999
2[0-1]\d\d= 2000-2199
22[0-2]\d = 2200-2229
223[0-4]  = 2230-2234
```

to form:

```
(1[1-9]\d|[2-9]\d\d|1\d\d\d|2[0-1]\d\d|22[0-2]\d|223[0-4])
```

*\d means [0-9], but in three less characters*

Answer (score 6):

While you *could* do it with some absurd looking regex (as VonC answered), regex really isn't supposed to do this.. Why not defer the number checking to the redirected-to-script?

If numbers 110-2234 go to script1, and 1-109 go to script2, it would be *much* simpler to direct all numbers at a `router` script, and have it redirect to the correct location (via HTTP redirects)..

In `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteRule ^view/([0-9]+)/?$ router.php?page=$1 [L]
```

..then in `router.php`, something like:

```
<?PHP
if(
   int($_GET['page']) > 110 &&
   int($_GET['page']) < 2234
){
    header("Status: 301 Moved Permanently\nLocation: /script1");
}else{
    header("Status: 404 Not Found");
}
?>
```

Comment: I know that. I would like to make it in .htaccess and avoid loading php and just load the right static file :-)

Answer (score 4):

It's possible allbeit not pretty.

```
\b(?:[1][1][0-9]|1\d{3}|223[0-4]|2[0-1]\d\d|2[0-2][0-3][0-4])\b
```

I emailed Phillip Hazel, the author of PCRE, in 2006 what he thought of math's in regex:

> Perhaps this lies out of the scope of the project in your view: The ability to treat numbers as being numbers and not text, this would definitely be a worthwhile feature.
>   Allowing you to do some basic math checks on matched digits, like: is the 2nd matched digit higher or lower, is the third digit a multiple off the 1st, and many more complicated cases I won't elaborate on just to get my point accross.
>   Do you feel this exceeds the realm of textmatching?

to which I got the following reply:

> Yes, I think I do, and also, it is not
>   something that is available in Perl
>   regular expressions. I know that PCRE
>   does have some extensions from Perl,
>   but nothing as major as that (you
>   could perhaps hack something up using
>   callouts, but that would be a bit ad
>   hoc, and no doubt exceedingly messy!).
>
> Philip

and I couldn't agree more now in `09. Just match all numbers and do number validation in whatever language you're doing the matching with.

Comment: I was reluctant to fix the quote's spelling, but I don't want the wrong spelling memes to spread.

Comment: This would not match the numbers in the range 120-199

Answer (score 0):

Also if you want to locate or find if your path name contains a year, and take it out as a string, you can try something like this:

```
path1 = r'X:\S\Something_2019\y2019\AB19778_description\subfolder1\subfolder2'
find = re.findall(r'.*(y[1-2][0,9][0-9]{2})', path1)
mystring = find[0]
print(mystring)
```

Checks in 'path1' if there is year string with format 'yYYYY'. So with letter 'y' as prefix (relevant for my study case).
This will return string 'y2019'.