# RegEx Numeric Check in Range?

Tags: regex

I'm new to StackOverflow, so please let me know if there is a better way to ask the following question.

I need to create a regular expression that detects whether a field in the database is numeric, and if it is numeric does it fall within a valid range (i.e. 1-50).  I've tried `[1-50]`, which works except for the instances where a single digit number is preceded by a 0 (i.e. 06).  06 should still be considered a valid number, since I can later convert that to a number.

I really appreciate your help!  I'm trying to learn more about regular expressions, and have been learning all I can from: [www.regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/).  If you guys have recommendations of other sites to bone up on this stuff I would appreciate it!

Comment: This related question might be helpful: [How to match numbers between X and Y with regexp?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/676467/)

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/676467/how-to-match-numbers-between-x-and-y-with-regexp

Comment: I wouldn't call it a duplicate; this is a special case of the other problem, and much simpler.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to match numbers between X and Y with regexp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/676467/how-to-match-numbers-between-x-and-y-with-regexp)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try this

```
^(0?[1-9])|([1-4][0-9])|(50)$
```

The idea of this regex is to break the problem down into cases

- 0?[1-9] takes care of the single digit case allowing for an optional preceeding 0
- [1-4][0-9] takes care of all numbers from 10 to 49.  This also allwows for a preceeding 0 on a single digit
- 50 takes care of 50

Comment: @ybo, yes it will.  But they said they wanted 06 so i assumed 00 was also valid.

Comment: @Jared, I removed my comment after your edit, but I still understand that he needs values between 1 and 50. 0 and 00 should be excluded, I think.

Comment: @ybo, you're correct.  I updated the answer to exclude all forms of 0

Comment: This works perfectly.  I did need to exclude 00, so this looks like it took care of it.  This site is awesome!  I appreciate everyone's help!

Comment: I think it should be ^0*([1-9])|([1-4][0-9])|(50)$, considering that 006 = 06 = 6, a number within the mathematical range [1,50], and similarly for 050. Or (faster I think) ^0*([1-4][0-9]?)|(50?)|([6-9])$

Answer (score 5):

Regular expressions work on characters (in this case digits), not numbers. You need to have a separate pattern for each number of digits in your pattern, and combine them with | (the OR operator) like the other answers have suggested. However, consider just checking if the text is numeric with a regular expression (like `[0-9]+`) and then converting to an integer and checking the integer is within range.

Answer (score 2):

You can't easily do range checking with regular expressions.  You can -- with some work -- develop a pattern that recognizes a numeric range, but it's usually quite complex, and difficult to modify for a slightly different range.

You're better off breaking this into two parts.

1. Recognize the number pattern (`^\d+$`).
2. Check the range of that number in an application program.

Answer (score 1):

^0?[1-50]{1,2}$