# Is there a "between" function in C#?

Tags: c#

Google doesn't understand that "between" is the name of the function I'm looking for and returns nothing relevant.

Ex: I want to check if 5 is between 0 and 10 in only one operation

Comment: it's kinda mathematecly impossible to do it one operation... have you tried writng your own?

Comment: The .NET libraries don't have *every* function under the sun. You still have to code some things yourself ;)

Comment: I was curious as SQL has a BETWEEN operator too, check this out, Jon made a LINQ equivalent http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1447635/linq-between-operator

Comment: ...which doesn't have the function either... :-/

Comment: MySql has but not c#

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to elegantly check if a number is within a range?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3188672/how-to-elegantly-check-if-a-number-is-within-a-range)

Comment: Hey my answer is a one liner I think you should change the correct answer to mine.

Comment: All good answers below, just adding that this seems like a great addition to the CoreLIb. Either as a `Math` method, if not something in the language itself.

Answer (score 95, accepted):

No, but you can write your own:

```
public static bool Between(this int num, int lower, int upper, bool inclusive = false)
{
    return inclusive
        ? lower <= num && num <= upper
        : lower < num && num < upper;
}
```

Comment: This might be useful, but Lambda expressions doesn't allow members with optional parameters. I'll go for an overload instead ;-)

Comment: that's not a lambda.  It's less than or equals to.

Answer (score 145):

It isn't clear what you mean by "one operation", but no, there's no operator / framework method that I know of to determine if an item is within a range.

You could of course write an extension-method yourself. For example, here's one that assumes that the interval is *closed* on both end-points.

```
public static bool IsBetween<T>(this T item, T start, T end)
{
    return Comparer<T>.Default.Compare(item, start) >= 0
        && Comparer<T>.Default.Compare(item, end) <= 0;
}
```

And then use it as:

```
bool b = 5.IsBetween(0, 10); // true
```

Comment: How would this behave for types that don't implement `IComparable<T>` or `IComparable`?

Comment: @Sam it will throw an exception but to avoid this you can add `where T : IComparable, IComparable<T>`

Comment: This should be the accepted solution; would be easy enough to add an "inclusive" parameter as well.

Comment: Great job, but if you dont't need this to be inclusive, and you want that 3 to be between 5 and 2 (as well as between 2 and 5), use this : `return Comparer<T>.Default.Compare(item, start) == -Comparer<T>.Default.Compare(item, end);`

Answer (score 35):

Here's a complete class.

```
/// <summary>
/// An extension class for the between operation
/// name pattern IsBetweenXX where X = I -> Inclusive, X = E -> Exclusive
/// <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/a/13470099/37055"></a>
/// </summary>
public static class BetweenExtensions
{

    /// <summary>
    /// Between check <![CDATA[min <= value <= max]]> 
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
    /// <param name="value">the value to check</param>
    /// <param name="min">Inclusive minimum border</param>
    /// <param name="max">Inclusive maximum border</param>
    /// <returns>return true if the value is between the min & max else false</returns>
    public static bool IsBetweenII<T>(this T value, T min, T max) where T:IComparable<T>
    {
        return (min.CompareTo(value) <= 0) && (value.CompareTo(max) <= 0);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Between check <![CDATA[min < value <= max]]>
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
    /// <param name="value">the value to check</param>
    /// <param name="min">Exclusive minimum border</param>
    /// <param name="max">Inclusive maximum border</param>
    /// <returns>return true if the value is between the min & max else false</returns>
    public static bool IsBetweenEI<T>(this T value, T min, T max) where T:IComparable<T>
    {
        return (min.CompareTo(value) < 0) && (value.CompareTo(max) <= 0);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// between check <![CDATA[min <= value < max]]>
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
    /// <param name="value">the value to check</param>
    /// <param name="min">Inclusive minimum border</param>
    /// <param name="max">Exclusive maximum border</param>
    /// <returns>return true if the value is between the min & max else false</returns>
    public static bool IsBetweenIE<T>(this T value, T min, T max) where T:IComparable<T>
    {
        return (min.CompareTo(value) <= 0) && (value.CompareTo(max) < 0);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// between check <![CDATA[min < value < max]]>
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
    /// <param name="value">the value to check</param>
    /// <param name="min">Exclusive minimum border</param>
    /// <param name="max">Exclusive maximum border</param>
    /// <returns>return true if the value is between the min & max else false</returns>

    public static bool IsBetweenEE<T>(this T value, T min, T max) where T:IComparable<T>
    {
        return (min.CompareTo(value) < 0) && (value.CompareTo(max) < 0);
    }
}
```

plus some unit test code

```
[TestClass]
public class UnitTest1
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethodIsBeetween()
    {
        Assert.IsTrue(5.0.IsBetweenII(5.0, 5.0));
        Assert.IsFalse(5.0.IsBetweenEI(5.0, 5.0));
        Assert.IsFalse(5.0.IsBetweenIE(5.0, 5.0));
        Assert.IsFalse(5.0.IsBetweenEE(5.0, 5.0));

        Assert.IsTrue(5.0.IsBetweenII(4.9, 5.0));
        Assert.IsTrue(5.0.IsBetweenEI(4.9, 5.0));
        Assert.IsFalse(5.0.IsBetweenIE(4.9, 5.0));
        Assert.IsFalse(5.0.IsBetweenEE(4.9, 5.0));

        Assert.IsTrue(5.0.IsBetweenII(5.0, 5.1));
        Assert.IsFalse(5.0.IsBetweenEI(5.0, 5.1));
        Assert.IsTrue(5.0.IsBetweenIE(5.0, 5.1));
        Assert.IsFalse(5.0.IsBetweenEE(5.0, 5.1));

        Assert.IsTrue(5.0.IsBetweenII(4.9, 5.1));
        Assert.IsTrue(5.0.IsBetweenEI(4.9, 5.1));
        Assert.IsTrue(5.0.IsBetweenIE(4.9, 5.1));
        Assert.IsTrue(5.0.IsBetweenEE(4.9, 5.1));

        Assert.IsFalse(5.0.IsBetweenII(5.1, 4.9));
        Assert.IsFalse(5.0.IsBetweenEI(5.1, 4.9));
        Assert.IsFalse(5.0.IsBetweenIE(5.1, 4.9));
        Assert.IsFalse(5.0.IsBetweenEE(5.1, 4.9));

    }
}
```

Comment: T should be IComparable<T> and not just IComparable, otherwise you get boxing

Answer (score 23):

Nope, you'll have to test each endpoint individually.

```
if ((x > 0) && (x < 10)) {
   // do stuff
}
```

Or if you want it to *look* more "betweeny", reorder the args:

```
if ((0 < x) && (x < 10)) {
   // do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 19):

So far, it looks like none of the answers have considered the likely possibility that dynamically, you don't know which value is the lower and upper bound.  For the general case, you could create your own IsBetween method that would probably go something like:

```
    public bool IsBetween(double testValue, double bound1, double bound2)
    {
        return (testValue >= Math.Min(bound1,bound2) && testValue <= Math.Max(bound1,bound2));
    }
```

Answer (score 16):

As of c# 9, you can do `5 is > 0 and < 10;` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-9#pattern-matching-enhancements

Answer (score 11):

There is no built in construct in C#/.NET, but you can easily add your own extension method for this:

```
public static class ExtensionsForInt32
{
    public static bool IsBetween (this int val, int low, int high)
    {
           return val > low && val < high;
    }
}
```

Which can be used like:

```
if (5.IsBetween (0, 10)) { /* Do something */ }
```

Comment: +1. Only caveat would be to set expectations to the consumer that the edge cases (0 and 10) are NOT inclusive. Otherwise, this is great!

Comment: I used a combination of this method and the one proposed by Ani. I added the IsBetween function to my extension class as a private member. Then I used public functions similar to this to expose the specific types I wanted to extend, which call to the private function.

Answer (score 7):

Except for the answer by @Ed G, all of the answers require knowing which bound is the lower and which is the upper one.

Here's a (rather non-obvious) way of doing it when you don't know which bound is which.

```
  /// <summary>
  /// Method to test if a value is "between" two other values, when the relative magnitude of 
  /// the two other values is not known, i.e., number1 may be larger or smaller than number2. 
  /// The range is considered to be inclusive of the lower value and exclusive of the upper 
  /// value, irrespective of which parameter (number1 or number2) is the lower or upper value. 
  /// This implies that if number1 equals number2 then the result is always false.
  /// 
  /// This was extracted from a larger function that tests if a point is in a polygon:
  /// http://www.ecse.rpi.edu/Homepages/wrf/Research/Short_Notes/pnpoly.html
  /// </summary>
  /// <param name="testValue">value to be tested for being "between" the other two numbers</param>
  /// <param name="number1">one end of the range</param>
  /// <param name="number2">the other end of the range</param>
  /// <returns>true if testValue >= lower of the two numbers and less than upper of the two numbers,
  ///          false otherwise, incl. if number1 == number2</returns>
  private static bool IsInRange(T testValue, T number1, T number2)
  {
     return (testValue <= number1) != (testValue <= number2);
  }
```

Note: This is NOT a generic method; it is pseudo code. The T in the above method should be replaced by a proper type, "int" or "float" or whatever. (There are ways of making this generic, but they're sufficiently messy that it's not worth while for a one-line method, at least not in most situations.)

Comment: programmers used to understand logic like this :)

Comment: I realize that this is "ancient" in Internet time, but I REALLY like this solution especially since it does not require the caller to know which bound is which.

Comment: The above sample IsInRange is close. The "testValue <= number1" needs to be >= and not <= or it will return invalid results.

Answer (score 6):

Wouldn't it be as simple as

```
0 < 5 && 5 < 10
```

?

So I suppose if you want a function out of it you could simply add this to a utility class:

```
public static bool Between(int num, int min, int max) {
    return min < num && num < max;
}
```

Comment: I expected something like bool x = Math.between(5,0,10), but I guess it doesn't exist so I'll have to stick with the bigger/smaller signs

Comment: Well, you could use extension methods I suppose.

Comment: Wadda ya know, check out Pete's answer.

Comment: The return type should be `bool`, not `void`.

Answer (score 5):

Generic function that is validated at compilation!

```
public static bool IsBetween<T>(this T item, T start, T end) where T : IComparable
{
    return item.CompareTo(start) >= 0 && item.CompareTo(end) <= 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
int val_to_check = 5
bool in_range = Enumerable.Range(0, 13).Contains(val_to_check);
```

The second parameter is the "count" not the end or high number.

I.E.

```
int low_num = 0
int high_num = 12
int val_to_check = 5
bool in_range = Enumerable.Range(low_num , high_num - low_num + 1).Contains(val_to_check);
```

Checks if the val_to_check is between 0 and 12

Comment: Things are gonna get gross when: `low_num = int.MinValue` and `high_num = int.MaxValue`. Nobody should be using this type of code to check if a value is between two other values.

Answer (score 2):

What about

```
somenumber == Math.Max(0,Math.Min(10,somenumber));
```

returns true when somenumber is 5.
returns false when somenumber is 11.

Comment: tbh, this does nothing much different from a simple expression `x >= a && x <= b` under the hood, but adds two unnecessary function calls.

Answer (score 1):

Refer to this link. A one line solution to that question.

[How to elegantly check if a number is within a range?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3188672/how-to-elegantly-check-if-a-number-is-within-a-range)

```
int x = 30;
if (Enumerable.Range(1,100).Contains(x))
//true

if (x >= 1 && x <= 100)
//true
```

I know the post is pretty old, but It may help others..

Comment: If this question is a duplicate of the question you've linked here, please flag it as a duplicate with the "flag" button under the question instead of leaving an answer to that effect. If it is not a duplicate, then please leave a complete answer instead of a link-only answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know that function; anyway if your value is unsigned, just one operation means (val < 11)... If it is signed, I think there is no atomic way to do it because 10 is not a power of 2...

Answer (score 0):

As @Hellfrost pointed out, it is literally nonsense to compare a number to two different numbers in "one operation", and I know of no C# operator that encapsulates this.

```
between = (0 < 5 && 5 < 10);
```

Is about the most-compact form I can think of.

You could make a somewhat "fluent"-looking method using [extension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx) (though, while amusing, I think it's overkill):

```
public static bool Between(this int x, int a, int b)
{
    return (a < x) && (x < b);
}
```

Use:

```
int x = 5;
bool b = x.Between(0,10);
```

Comment: so this does NOT exist in c#, I know for sure this is natively supported in python

Comment: That's 'cause batteries are sold separately with C#. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Base @Dan J this version don't care max/min, more like sql :)

```
public static bool IsBetween(this decimal me, decimal a, decimal b, bool include = true)
{
    var left = Math.Min(a, b);
    var righ = Math.Max(a, b);

    return include
        ? (me >= left && me <= righ)
        : (me > left && me < righ)
    ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or if you want to bound the value to the interval:

```
public static T EnsureRange<T>(this T value, T min, T max) where T : IComparable<T>
    {
        if (value.CompareTo(min) < 0)
            return min;
        else if (value.CompareTo(max) > 0)
            return max;
        else
            return value;
    }
```

It is like two-sided Math.Min/Max

Answer (score 0):

And for negatives values:

```
    Public Function IsBetween(Of T)(item As T, pStart As T, pEnd As T) As Boolean ' https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/bb384936.aspx
    Dim Deb As T = pStart
    Dim Fin As T = pEnd
    If (Comparer(Of T).Default.Compare(pStart, pEnd) > 0) Then Deb = pEnd : Fin = pStart
    Return Comparer(Of T).Default.Compare(item, Deb) >= 0 AndAlso Comparer(Of T).Default.Compare(item, Fin) <= 0
End Function
```