# Extension methods for struct types

Tags: c#, extension-methods

i have these two duplicated methods as extension methods , but i want to condense them into only one extension method ,

i have thought of using constraint : Where T : Struct ,

but then what about bool , other struct types , is there a way to limit only to int decimal float long etc.

```
   public static bool IsBetween(this double value, double lowerBound, double upperBound)
    {
        return value >= lowerBound && value <= upperBound;
    }


    public static bool IsBetween(this decimal value, decimal lowerBound, decimal upperBound)
    {
        return value >= lowerBound && value <= upperBound;
    }
```

Comment: There is currently no abstraction over different numeric types. The [shapes proposal](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/164) might allow this in future.

Comment: so is it that i have to duplicate for the types i want

Comment: In general, yes. That is what the `Math` class currently does. In this specific case, you could write a generic method on types which are `IComparable<T>`

Comment: you don't *have* to - but it might be *simpler* to; you could also change `>=` and `<=` to checking `Comparer<T>.Default.Compare(value, lowerBound)` etc, and test the reply -ve/0/+ve; this won't enforce things at compile-time, but it should *work* at least; it is probably *easier* just to write multiple methods, though

Comment: Given that this question is specifically about comparisons though, you could write `bool IsBetween<T>(this T value, T lower, T upper) where T : IComparable<T>` then use `value.CompareTo(lower)`, etc. Although the normal practice is to use `Comparer<T>.Default`, restricting to `IComparable<T>` would stop this extension method appearing for all types. I wish @CodeCaster hadn't closed it - I think there's a viable answer there.

Comment: @CodeCaster I was failing to find a duplicate which had an answer which uses generics constrained to `IComparable<T>`, but have since found one. I don't have the rights to add it as a dup, though: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5023213/is-there-a-between-function-in-c/11252952

Comment: @canton are sure that's the one you mean? "Is there a “between” function in C#?" It _shows_ how to use that, but that's not really the question.

Comment: @CodeCaster Yes. The OP's question is about an `IsBetween` method, and the 2nd answer in my proposed dup has the method I was suggesting.