# Dragging an item vertically, Y position not working

Tags: c#, winforms, drag-and-drop, panel, picturebox

I have a picturebox which displays an image of a music note. I want to be able to change the value of the pitch when dragging it up and down inside the panel which contains it according to the corresponding Y position of where it is dropped. Using the code below, the pitch does change, but it seems that the Y value is just random, when it should be going up the higher I drag and down the lower I drag.

```
private void StartDrag(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
            {
                isDragging = true;
                pitch = e.Y;
                this.Location = new Point(this.Location.X, pitch);
            }

        }

        private void StopDrag(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
            {
                isDragging = false;
                pitch = e.Y;
            }

        }

        private void NoteDrag(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (isDragging)
            {
                this.Top = this.Top + (e.Y - this.pitch); //move in Vertical direction
            }
        }
```

Comment: Cant you style a slider for this?

Comment: I am unfamiliar with sliders as I am new to C#. Would it be possible for each music note to have its own slider? As in the program multiple notes can be added

Comment: These musical note dragging questions are relentless this week.  Must be some kind of homework assignment.

Comment: Styling a slider is probably a reference to web/WPF/Silverlight controls. If you are not restricted to winforms, this sounds like a good fit for WPF or Silverlight. This kind of interaction would be simpler.

Comment: @Hans: I agree, I thought it's the same guy.

Comment: Yes it is an assignment, but most of the questions posted are about work or assignments. When you're stuck it's usually quicker to ask here than wait for a professor to answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unusual dragging issue in C# WinForm](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8596256/unusual-dragging-issue-in-c-sharp-winform)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you change the position of your control (by modifying `this.Top`), mouse coordinates returned with `MouseEventArgs`   also change. Instead of using the `e` parameter, you should use [`Cursor.Position`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.cursor.position.aspx) to get **absolute (screen) coordinates**, and then transform them using the [`PointToClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.pointtoclient%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) method of your **parent** control. That way your coordinates will be independent of the position of your control.

To get a better understanding what happens, before doing all this, add two labels to your form, and add something like this inside your `NoteDrag` method:

```
// show relative coordinate 
this.label1.Text = e.Y.ToString();

// show absolute coordinate 
this.label2.Text = Cursor.Position.Y.ToString();
```

Comment: I accepted because it really helped me understand what's going on, thanks a lot!