# How to elegantly assign values in function of number range?

Tags: c#, numbers, range

I am searching of an elegant way to assign values in function of a number belonging to a specific range.

For example, having the number X, the `elegant way` would return:

- 'a' - if X is between 0 and 1000
- 'b' - if X is between 1000 and 1500
- and so on (but a fixed number of defined intervals)

By elegant I mean something more appealing than

```
if ((x => interval_1) && (x < interval_2))
    class_of_x = 'a';
else if ((x => interval_2) && (x < interval_3))
    class_of_x = 'b';
...
```

or

```
if(Enumerable.Range(interval_1, interval_2).Contains(x))
    class_of_x = 'a';
else if(Enumerable.Range(interval_2 + 1, interval_3).Contains(x))
    class_of_x = 'b';
...
```

I hate seeing so many IFs.
Also, the interval values can be stored in a collection (maybe this would help me eliminate the ISs?), not necessary as interval_1, interval_2 and so on.

Somewhat inspired by this question [How to elegantly check if a number is within a range?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3188672/how-to-elegantly-check-if-a-number-is-within-a-range) which came out while looking for a solution for the problem described above.

Comment: does the next interval always start from the end of the previous?

Comment: @Sayse: In my case, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create extention method:

```
public static class IntExtensions
{
    // min inclusive, max exclusive
    public static bool IsBetween(this int source, int min, int max)
    {
        return source >= min && source < max
    }
}
```

and then

```
// Item1 = min, Item2 = max, Item3 = character class
IList<Tuple<int, int, char>> ranges = new List<Tuple<int, int, char>>();
// init your ranges here
int num = 1;
// assuming that there certainly is a range which fits num,
// otherwise use "OrDefault"
// it may be good to create wrapper for Tuple, 
// or create separate class for your data
char characterClass = ranges.
                        First(i => num.IsBetween(i.Item1, i.Item2)).Item3;
```

Answer (score 1):

If my comment is correct then your first if statement has a lot of unnecessary checks, if its not less than interval 2 then it must be greater than or equal to, therefore:

```
if((x => i1) && (x < i2))
else if(x < i3)
else if(x < i4)...
```

When a "true" argument is found then the rest of the if statement is irrelevant, as long as your conditions are in order this should suit your needs

Comment: Seems I have overlooked this for sure. :D Less code, but still a lot of IFs.

Comment: Other than this there isn't really a way to avoid lots of if statements, you could always do some combination of math.round and a switch statement I guess but thats not really achieving much

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, define a little class to hold the inclusive maximum value, and the corresponding value to use for that band:

```
sealed class Band
{
    public int  InclusiveMax;
    public char Value;
}
```

Then declare an array of `Band` which specifies the value to use for each band and loop to find the corresponding band value for any input:

```
public char GetSetting(int input)
{
    var bands = new[]
    {
        new Band {InclusiveMax = 1000, Value = 'a'},
        new Band {InclusiveMax = 1500, Value = 'b'},
        new Band {InclusiveMax = 3000, Value = 'c'}
    };

    char maxSetting = 'd';

    foreach (var band in bands)
        if (input <= band.InclusiveMax)
            return band.Value;

    return maxSetting;
}
```

Note: In real code, you would wrap all this into a class which initialises the `bands` array only once, and not every single time it's called (as it is in the code above).

Answer (score 1):

Create an Interval class and use LINQ:

```
public class Interval
{
    public string TheValue { get; set; }
    public int Start { get; set; }
    public int End { get; set; }

    public bool InRange(int x)
    {
        return x >= this.Start && x <= this.End;
    }
}

public void MyMethod()
{
    var intervals = new List<Interval>();

    // Add them here...

    var x = 3213;
    var correctOne = intervals.FirstOrDefault(i => i.InRange(x));

    Console.WriteLine(correctOne.TheValue);
}
```

Comment: given the inputs specified in the question, your own code would cause an NRE on the bottom line

Comment: And given this is a very simple example of a pattern and not a complete code piece that should simply be copy-pasted, I didn't add an if-statement.

Comment: See my alternative version with the use of Linq's static Enumerable.Range() method below...

Answer (score 0):

Here you could also use the static System.Linq.Enumerable's Range() method that implements

```
IEnumerable<T>
```

with the Contains() method (again from System.Linq.Enumerable), to do something like:

```
var num = 254;
if(Enumerable.Range(100,300).Contains(num)) { ...your logic here; }
```

This looks more elegant in my eyes at least.