# Pulling a range from an array

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

So I don’t want anyone to solve it but just help me out in terms of working a certain part. So out of the array I have to print a certain numbers that fit within the range given(0 & 50). Besides manually putting  `array[i]>= 0 && array[i] <=50`

How can I make it so it test over multiple values and draws the numbers from there. I seem to be stuck on that part.

Comment: See [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3188672/how-to-elegantly-check-if-a-number-is-within-a-range) at C#. you can apply the solutions to JS too.

Comment: Are you asking about JavaScript or Java? They are different languages.

Comment: @JJJ java im sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Edit (credits  Guy Yogev):

```js
function getRange(arr, min, max) {
  return arr.filter(function(entry) { return entry >= min && entry <= max; })
}

var testArr = [1, 2, 5, 10, 20, 30, 22, 4, 100];

console.log(getRange(testArr, 3, 10));
```

Comment: Wouldn't [Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) be simpler to use?

Comment: yes, you're right. don't know what I was thinking about

Answer (score 0):

The clean solution in java would be using streams. You can do much more than just filter, but this would solve your question.

```
int[] filterByRange(int[] array, int min, int max) {
    return Arrays.stream(array)
            .filter(i -> min <= i && i<= max)
            .toArray(int[]::new);
}
```

Answer (score -4):

```
array.slice(0,51)
```

This is

```
array[i]>= 0 && array[i] < 51
```

Comment: Thanks but how do I make it to where it’s testing multiple times over different values and ranges. Like the user inputs the range and it’s not a set range?

Comment: array.slice takes out elements from an array, in your case the first 51, it doesn't check its value

Comment: I don't think the question is about the index "0" and "50". It is more about to check if any element at x index, I mean A[x] is "more than numeric value 0 and less than value 50" or not

Comment: @KushagrArora yes exactly!