# How do I solve this problem with my code? C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've tried adding a `)` where it says to, but that adds more problems. The error I get states:

> Assets/LevelComplete.cs(12,64): error CS1026: ) expected.

What I'm trying to do here is use the if statement to find out if the Active Scene is in the specific range. Also, for a little more context, All I need is a range, and not the code to pick a number in that range if that helps.

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class LEvelComplete : MonoBehavior
{
    public void LoadNextLevel()
    {
        int Active12 = Range(1, 3);
        int Load34 = UnityEngine.Random.Range(3, 5);

        if (SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex = Active12
        {
            SceneManager.LoadScene(Load34);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Updated my Answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "find out if the Active Scene is in the specific range."

...

```
var scene = SceneManager.GetActiveScene(); 
if (scene.buildIndex >= 1 && scene.buildIndex <= 3)
```

... or if you prefer Linq:

```
if (Active12.Contains(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex))
```

See also [How to elegantly check if a number is within a range?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3188672/how-to-elegantly-check-if-a-number-is-within-a-range/19854639)

Comment: I tried this and it said that "Non invocable member "scene.buildindex" cannot be used like a method

Comment: sorry that's just a typo on my part, it's a property so shouldn't have the brackets after it (which would be used for a method call). Try the updated version above.

Comment: Thanks So much it worked. You don't know how much this is gonna help my game!

Answer (score 2):

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using Random = UnityEngine.Random;

public class question_63947858_script_error : MonoBehaviour
{
    public void LoadNextLevel()
    {
        int Active12 = Random.Range(1, 3);
        int Load34 = Random.Range(3, 5);

        if (SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex == Active12)
        {
            SceneManager.LoadScene(Load34);
        }
    }
}
```

Things wrong:

1. MonoBehaviour was spelled wrong
2. System was clashing  with UnityEngine namespace. So disambiguated with Random = UnityEngine.Random
3. No parentheses after the if statement
4. =  changed to == in the if statement