# Regex for set "x/x" or "x of x"

Tags: regex, string, parsing

I would like some help for detecting the following expressions with RegEx:

string "(x/x)" where x is any number from 0-999.
string "x of x" where x is any number from 0-999.

Typically, the string is a marker for a set, i.e. 4 of 10 things, or (3/5) where the first number is the item and the second number is the total.

Comment: what language? or what flavor of regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
\d{1,3}/\d{1,3}
```

and

```
\d{1,3} of \d{1,3}
```

Comment: This will match 000 and the like, which may or may not be acceptable.  And in Perl 5.8 and 5.10 \d will match things that are not [0-9] (such as MONGOLIAN DIGIT 5 U+1815)

Comment: Good point. /d may not be as explicit as I need it to be. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
\([0-9]+\/[0-9]+\)
```

and

```
[0-9]+ of [0-9]+
```

Comment: This will match 000 and the like, which may or may not be acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

See [How to match numbers between X and Y with regexp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/676467).

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $num_re = qr/[0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9]{2}/;
for my $s qw( 1/10 100/500 a/456) {
    if (my ($x, $y) = $s =~ m{^($num_re)/($num_re)$}) {
        print "x is $x and y is $y\n";
    } else {
        print "$s does not match\n";
    }
}
```

or just

```
^([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9]{2})\/([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9]{2})$
```

if you don't mind violating [DRY](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?DontRepeatYourself).