# Regular expression for numbers without leading zeros

Tags: regex

I need a regular expression to match any number from 0 to 99. Leading zeros may not be included, this means that f.ex. 05 is not allowed.

I know how to match 1-99, but do not get the 0 included.

My regular expression for 1-99 is

```
^[1-9][0-9]?$
```

Comment: This was almost right, but you just had your optional argument '?' on the second digit instead of the leading digit.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**Updated:**

```
^([0-9]|[1-9][0-9])$
```

Matches 0-99. Doesn't match values with leading zeros. Depending on your application you may need to escape the parentheses and the or symbol.

Comment: He doen't want leading zeros on for instance `05` (which this expressions actually matches).

Comment: I understood "may not be included" as leading zeros were optional.

Comment: That doesn't work for single digit numbers (e.g. `9`). Also, you could also shrink it down a bit: `^(0|[1-9]\d?)$`.

Answer (score 48):

There are plenty of ways to do it but here is an alternative to allow any number length without leading zeros

0-99:

```
^(0|[1-9][0-9]{0,1})$
```

0-999 (just increase {0,**2**}):

```
^(0|[1-9][0-9]{0,2})$
```

1-99:

```
^([1-9][0-9]{0,1})$
```

1-100:

```
^([1-9][0-9]{0,1}|100)$
```

Any number in the world

```
^(0|[1-9][0-9]*)$
```

12 to 999

```
^(1[2-9]|[2-9][0-9]{1}|[1-9][0-9]{2})$
```

Comment: If I want to add range between 12 to 999 then what would be the regex?

Comment: Any defined range can be [generated **here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67502416/5527985) (check [•] *match whole string*).

Answer (score 4):

```
^(0|[1-9][0-9]?)$
```

Test here http://regexr.com?2uu31 (various samples included)

You have to add a `0|`, but be aware that the "or" (`|`) in Regexes has the lowest precedence.  `^0|[1-9][0-9]?$` in reality means `(^0)|([1-9][0-9]?$)` (we will ignore that now there are two capturing groups). So it means "the string begins with `0`" OR "the string ends with `[1-9][0-9]?`". An alternative to using brackets is to repeat the `^$`, like `^0$|^[1-9][0-9]?$`.

Comment: I tried everything but not this.. :( Why do I need the outer brackets?? I don´t understand.

Comment: @Jan-FrederikCarl Because the `|` has precedence nothing. So without the brackets, `^0|[1-9][0-9]?$ == (?:^0)|(?:[1-9][0-9]?$)` (where `(?: )` is the non-capturing group). But what you want is something equivalent to `(?:^0$)|(?:^[1-9][0-9]?$)`

Answer (score 2):

> ***[...] but do not get the 0 included.***

Just add `0|...` in front of the expression:

```
^(0|[1-9][0-9]?)$
  ^^
```

Comment: What you tested doesn't match your expression here.

Answer (score 2):

A simpler answer without using the or operator makes the leading digit optional:

```
^[1-9]?[0-9]$
```

Matches 0-99 disallowing leading zeros (01-09).

Comment: This only works for two-digit numbers, unlike most examples here.

Answer (score 2):

```js
console.log(/^0(?! \d+$)/.test('0123')); // true
console.log(/^0(?! \d+$)/.test('10123')); // false
console.log(/^0(?! \d+$)/.test('00123')); // true
console.log(/^0(?! \d+$)/.test('088770123')); // true
```

How about this?

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
^(?:0|[1-9][0-9]?)$
```

Answer (score 1):

Answer:

`^([1-9])?(\d)$`

Explanation:

```
^          // beginning of the string
([1-9])?   // first group (optional) in range 1-9 (not zero here)
(\d)       // second group matches any digit including 0
$          // end of the string
```

Same as (Not grouping):

`^[1-9]?\d$`

Test:

https://regex101.com/r/Tpe9Ia/1

Answer (score 0):

Try this it will help you

```
^([0-9]|[1-9][0-9])$
```

Answer (score 0):

```
([1-9][0-9]+).*
```

this will be simple and efficient
it will help with any range of whole numbers

```
([1-9][0-9\.]+).*
```

this expression will help with decimal numbers

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your second pattern allows more then one decimal point.

Comment: Your first pattern allows digit sequences with more than two digits.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following regex:

```
[1-9][0-9]\d|0
```

Comment: That matches either the single digit `0` or a three-digit number. The question asked for 0 to 99.

Answer (score -1):

```
^(0{1,})?([1-9][0-9]{0,1})$
```

It includes:
1-99,
01-099,
00...1-

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.