# Remove all alphabetical characters and leading zeros from strings in an array with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, string, data-manipulation

Thanks for taking your time to read my question.

I need to remove all **alphabetical** characters **and** leading zeros from string elements in an array. The array will look something like this:

`["DE73456","DE71238","FR00034","FR00036","ES00038","US00039","DE00098", ...]`

The result should be the following array of **integers**:

`[73456,71238,34,36,38,39,98, ...]`

Eventually, I would like to determine **the lowest omitted value from this ascending sorted list of numbers**. I alreay found a JS function that would do the job by passing an integer array - and it works perfectly as desired.

Maybe we can somehow integrate the above mentioned requirement with the JS function below to determine the lowest omitted value.

```
var k = [73456,71238,34,36,38,39,98];

k.sort(function(a, b) { return a-b; });   // To sort by numeric

var offset = k[0];
var lowest = -1;
for (i = 0;  i < k.length;  ++i) {
  if (k[i] != offset) {
    lowest = offset;
    break;
  }
  ++offset;
}
if (lowest == -1) {
    lowest = k[k.length - 1] + 1;
}
return lowest;
```

So, in a nutshell, I would like to determine the **lowest omitted value** from an array of strings.

`["DE73456","DE71238","FR00034","FR00036","ES00038","US00039","DE00098", ...]`

Consequently, the **result** of the JS function should return **35** for the example stated above.

Thank you very much for your suggestions! I am looking forward to reading your comments.

Comment: maybe helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7753976/regular-expression-for-numbers-without-leading-zeros

Comment: If you remove all characters from a string, the string will be empty.  I think you meant "alphabetical characters"?

Comment: You are right @JoelFan, the qustion was not very well stated in this regard. I´ve edited the question - thanks for pointing this out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the provided list sample a [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) like ... [`(/^[0\D]+/)`](https://regex101.com/r/ZSDGvC/2/) ... already is sufficient enough in order to be used for string [`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Syntax)ment. Since this task, and also the additional task of [casting a string into a number value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number#Convert_numeric_strings_and_null_to_numbers), has to be processed for every array item, one wants to use [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

In order to achieve the final result wished by the OP, one has to implement a function which *gets the lowest omitted value from an unordered list of integers* ...

```js
const sampleList = ["DE73456","DE71238","FR00034","FR00036","ES00038","US00039","DE00098"];

// for the above samples a regex like ... /^[0\D]+/ ... already
// is sufficient enough ... [https://regex101.com/r/ZSDGvC/1/]

// an unsorted list of integers ...
console.log(
  sampleList
    .map(sample => Number(sample.replace((/^[0\D]+/), '')))
);


function getLowestOmittedValueFromIntegerList(list) {
  let lowestOmittedInteger;
  let hasOmittedValue = false;

  const maximumListCount = (list.length - 1);

  // use shallow copy for not mutating the original
  // ... and sort this new array in ascending order.
  list = Array.from(list).sort((a, b) => (a - b));

  // look for omitted value, save it and exit early.
  list.some((integer, idx) => {

    if (idx < maximumListCount) {
      if ((integer + 1) < list[idx + 1]) {

        lowestOmittedInteger = (integer + 1);
        hasOmittedValue = true;
      }
    }
    return hasOmittedValue;
  });

  return lowestOmittedInteger;
}

// the lowest omitted value from an unsorted list of integers ...
console.log(
  getLowestOmittedValueFromIntegerList(
    sampleList
      .map(sample => Number(sample.replace((/^[0\D]+/), '')))
  )
);

// proof of concept ...
console.log('\nproof of concept ...\n\n');

console.log( // expect the undefined value
  getLowestOmittedValueFromIntegerList([9,8,7,6,6,6,5,4,3,2,1,0])
);
console.log( // expect 7 
  getLowestOmittedValueFromIntegerList([9,8,6,6,6,5,4,3,2,1,0])
);

console.log( // expect 11
  getLowestOmittedValueFromIntegerList([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,12])
);
console.log( // expect the undefined value
  getLowestOmittedValueFromIntegerList([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12])
);

console.log( // expect -1
  getLowestOmittedValueFromIntegerList([-4,-3,-2,0,1,2,3,4])
);
console.log( // expect -2
  getLowestOmittedValueFromIntegerList([-4,-3,-1,0,1,2,3,4])
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks Peter. However, I am looking for the lowest **unused** number within the range of the resulting array of integers. Thanks for helping out.

Comment: @nairolf ... Which for the provided example would be?.. It is not quite clear from your explanation. Would it be `36` because this number sequence does not appear in all the other extracted numbers?

Comment: It would be 35. If you look at this part of the string array, 35 would be the lowest unused number within the range of the resulting integer array. `["FR00034","FR00036","ES00038","US00039"]`

Comment: Which is ... *"get the lowest omitted value from an ascending sorted list of numbers*" ... a range is something different ... anyhow I'm already working on it ...

Comment: thanks for the clarification and your assistance. Much appreciated!

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I am new to this platform, it was late already, and it seems like I up voted the wrong suggestion. I´ve corrected it. Thank you very much again for your assistance!

Answer (score 3):

You can use this simple regex replacement:

```
repl = str.replace(/^[a-zA-Z]+0*/, "")
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/noeZ2x/2)

**RegEx Details:**

- `^`: Start
- `[a-zA-Z]+`: Match an alphabet
- `0*`: Match zero or more `0`s
- Replacement is just an empty string

Answer (score 3):

You could also use a single character class `^[A-Z0]+` to match 1 or more occurrences of A-Z or a 0 from the start of the string `^` and then use array map.

```
s = s.replace(/^[A-Z0]+/, "")
```

```js
const a = ["DE73456", "DE71238", "FR00034", "FR00036", "ES00038", "US00039", "DE00098"];
console.log(a.map(s => s.replace(/^[A-Z0]+/, "")))
```

Comment: Thank you very much! The merged code actually did the job.  `const a = ["DE73456", "DE71238", "FR00034", "FR00036", "ES00038", "US00039", "DE00098"];
console.log(a.map(s => s.replace(/^[A-Z0]+/, "")))

var k = a.map(s => s.replace(/^[A-Z0]+/, ""));

k.sort(function(a, b) { return a-b; });   // To sort by numeric

var offset = k[0];
var lowest = -1;
for (i = 0;  i < k.length;  ++i) {
  if (k[i] != offset) {
    lowest = offset;
    break;
  }
  ++offset;
}
if (lowest == -1) {
    lowest = k[k.length - 1] + 1;
}
console.log("Lowest = " + lowest);`

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `match` instead of removing the unwanted characters.

```js
str = "FR00034"
str.match(/[1-9][0-9]*/)
```

**RegEx Details:**

- `[1-9]`: the first character should be non zero number
- `[0-9]*`: all the following numbers

---

The final function to get the lowest of all should look something like this.

```js
function getLowestOf() {
    const numbers = arr.map((item) => Number(item.match(/[1-9][0-9]*/)[0]));
    const sorted = numbers.sort((a, b) => a - b);
    // console.log(sorted);
    return sorted[0];
}
const arr = ["DE73456","DE71238","FR00034","FR00036","ES00038","US00039","DE00098"];
console.log(getLowestOf(arr))
```