# regular expression for csv numbers from 1 to 1000

Tags: php, javascript, regex

I need a regex that can match a string of numbers from 1 to 1000 separated by commas.

> eg : 12,56,100,190,900,1000

I am using javascript on the front end and php on the back end for validation.  Ideally, I need a common regex, which will work for both.

Comment: This isn't a question. What are you trying to do what? What isn't working?

Comment: Also please add more info: Which language are you using? Why regex and not a CSV parser?

Comment: i need to allow only number between 1 to 1000 separated by commas in a html field

Comment: Yes, you said that before (except for the HTML bit - what does *that* have to do with it? HTML and CSV are two very different concepts). You didn't answer our questions, though. Please provide more info.

Comment: i am using regex because i need it to allow values  from 1 to 1000 separated by commas in a html field

Comment: i cant use a csv parser to validate input in html elements. right?

Comment: Oh dear, this isn't going anywhere useful. Please: Show an excerpt of the *actual*  data you have. Show the code you're using so far to deal with it. Show what isn't working the way you expect it to. Otherwise, there's not much we can do.

Comment: Not a lot of info in this question, but... [This site](http://www.regular-expressions.info/numericranges.html) explains how to match multi-digit numbers with regular expressions. [This StackOverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/676467/how-to-match-numbers-between-x-and-y-with-regexp) asks how to match multi-digit numbers with regular expressions. [This site](http://utilitymill.com/utility/Regex_For_Range) generates the regular expressions for checking numbers in a range. And have you considered that regular expressions may not be the best way of doing this? Split the string on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to match the entire line, than something like this should do:

```
^([1-9][0-9]{0,2}|1000)(,([1-9][0-9]{0,2}|1000))*$
```

Depending on your requirements, you may also want to allow whitespace in the beginning, end, and/or after commas.

This will allow whitespace in the beginning:
`^\s*([1-9][0-9]{0,2}|1000)(,([1-9][0-9]{0,2}|1000))*$`

This will allow whitespace at the end:
`^([1-9][0-9]{0,2}|1000)(,([1-9][0-9]{0,2}|1000))*\s*$`

This will allow whitespaces after commas:
`^([1-9][0-9]{0,2}|1000)(,\s*([1-9][0-9]{0,2}|1000))*$`

Combine these to your liking.

**EDIT 2:** If you want to allow a comma in the binning or at the end, then your regex becomes

```
^,?([1-9][0-9]{0,2}|1000)(,\s*([1-9][0-9]{0,2}|1000))*,?$
```

Here, `,?` means that you can have 0 or 1 comma.

**EDIT:** explanation, as requested:

- `^` in the beginning and `$` at the end are start/end of input marks - they ensure that we test the entire input
- Parentheses work just as you would expect them
- `[1-9]` matches a digit 1 through 9, similarly `[0-9]` matches a digit 0 through 9
- `{0,2}` indicates that the previous part (in our case `[0-9]`) is present between 0 and 2 times
- `|` is a logical `OR` - either part before it matches or the part after it

Thus in the first set of parentheses we match digit 1 to 9 followed by 0, 1 or 2 digits 0 to 9 - this gives us numbers between 1 and 999 - or we match 1000.

Then we match a comma followed by the same block as described above - and this lot is matched 0 or more times - as indicated by `*` character after the parentheses.

Comment: thanks aleks it works fine. but i didn't quite get how. do you mind giving an explanation

Comment: @SaurabhSingh: Which part don't you understand?

Comment: @TimPietzcker i didnt understand why does it give an error if the string is 1, or 400, i mean the last character is a comma

Comment: @SaurabhSingh Is an error in this case a correct result?  Or do you want to allow for it?

Comment: i want to allow for it but how is it working i wanted to understand that

Comment: @SaurabhSingh Currently it's not allowed because the regex specifies that a comma must be followed by another number.  I updated my answer to show how to allow a command at the start/end

Comment: according to the regex if comma is entered at the end then the regex should be true right?

Comment: ok so we are checking the the comma is always followed by a number as well..got it

Comment: @SaurabhSingh The original regex - no; the one in _edit 2_ will.

Answer (score 3):

Numbers in the range 1-1000, separated commas, is matched by

```
(?<=,|^)([1-9][0-9]{0,2}|1000)(?=,|$)
```

Comment: good, unless OP wants it in javascript

Comment: And it doesn't validate whether the entire string contains only valid numbers. It will just pick the valid numbers from it. If it's applied repeatedly to the string. The original question is so vague that it's hard to tell whether this matters, but the word "validation" gives me pause. One single correct value would be enough for the regex to report success, quite possibly not what Saurabh wants.

Comment: This pattern will match `123,abc` - but he needs to have a CSV line of numbers.

Comment: Thanks carlpett and Tim.
FYI
i am using javascript on the front end and php on the backend to validate this input and i need a common regex which can work for both is it possible.

Comment: @SaurabhSingh: This regex requires lookahead and lookbehind, but since we do not know exactly what strings are accepted and which (if any) should not match at all, it was just a guess as to what you could want. So, what is ok, and what is not? What about spaces?

Comment: @SaurabhSingh: Why didn't you write this in your question? That is the place where this information is needed. Otherwise *we cannot help you*  without becoming extremely frustrated.

Comment: @TimPietzcker: sorry Tim i'll put it up there as well