# Regex number between 1 and 100

Tags: regex, string

I searched a lot and can't find the solution for this RegExp (I have to say I'm not very experienced in Reg. Expressions).

```
Regex = ^[1-9]?[0-9]{1}$|^100$
```

I would like to test a number **between 1 and 100, excluding 0**

Comment: Why not parse as number, and test for `(x >= 1) AND (x <= 100)`?

Comment: U can use a simple if condition.

Comment: dont solve this using regex...

Comment: possible duplicate of [regular expression for csv numbers from 1 to 1000](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12909137/regular-expression-for-csv-numbers-from-1-to-1000)

Comment: @Martijn: One reason is that ASP.NET webforms validation controls use offer RegEx-based validation. And this would not only ensure numeric input but a range for input of a percentage with a single validation control.

Comment: @DanielPrzybylski: ASP.NET webform validation controls also include *RangeValidator*, which would be far more appropriate in this case.

Comment: I hit this question because I'm dealing with a 3rd party xml in a programming app, and there's no choice but to use regex. ASP.NET was an example, but not the only one so it doesn't matter if there's a better choice in THAT problem space.

Answer (score 125, accepted):

Try:

```
^[1-9][0-9]?$|^100$
```

[**Working fiddle**](http://regex101.com/r/gT8wK5)

EDIT: IF you want to match 00001, 00000099 try

```
^0*(?:[1-9][0-9]?|100)$
```

**[FIDDLE](http://regex101.com/r/mN1iT5)**

Comment: Interesting website Ankur, but I would love to found a list to choose the regex engine.

Comment: @sputnick I don't know about other engines but http://regexpal.com/ tests for javascript regex

Comment: @GillesQuenot You can pick the regex flavour from the left side bar

Comment: This works for me, hence the upvote for Ankur. Thanks.

Comment: If there is a need to support any amount of decimals: `^(?:[1-9]\d?(?:\.\d+)?|100(?:\.0+)?)$`. If only two decimals: ``^(?:[1-9]\d?(?:\.\d{1,2})?|100(?:\.00?)?)$``

Answer (score 18):

For integers from 1 to 100 with no preceding 0 try:

```
^[1-9]$|^[1-9][0-9]$|^(100)$
```

For integers from 0 to 100 with no preceding 0 try:

```
^[0-9]$|^[1-9][0-9]$|^(100)$
```

Regards

Answer (score 15):

**Here are very simple** regex's to understand (verified, and no preceding 0)

Between 0 to 100 ([**Try it here**](https://regex101.com/r/2i9qz8/3)):

```
^(0|[1-9][0-9]?|100)$
```

Between 1 to 100 ([**Try it here**](https://regex101.com/r/2i9qz8/4)):

```
^([1-9][0-9]?|100)$
```

Answer (score 9):

Try it,
This will work more efficiently..
1. For number ranging 00 - 99.99 (decimal inclusive)

```
^([0-9]{1,2}){1}(\.[0-9]{1,2})?$
```

Working fiddle link

https://regex101.com/r/d1Kdw5/1/

2.For number ranging 1-100(inclusive) with no preceding 0.

```
(?:\b|-)([1-9]{1,2}[0]?|100)\b
```

Working Fiddle link

http://regex101.com/r/mN1iT5/6

Comment: Check it on fiddle. Link is there.

Comment: I have edited the expression. There was slight mistake. Check it now.

Comment: I think it would be more helpful for the OP and further visitor, when you add some explanation to your intension.

Comment: Hmm.  Still not - it won't match 100 and will match (for example) 11.33

Comment: This expression is for numbers 1 to 99 including decimal numbers.

Comment: In its current form, your regex matches numbers in the range **00 to 99.99**.  The OP said he wanted to match numbers from **1 to 100** (inclusive), and he didn't say anything about decimals.  I'm pretty sure he didn't want the leading zeroes, either.

Comment: Thank you @AlanMoore for suggestion. I have edited my expression. Hope this will as per your expectation.

Comment: ...and then some!  Correct **and** creative; gets an upvote from me.

Comment: the first regex doesn't match the number 20

Comment: @Ved  I have small request, can I have regular expression in between 1 to 100, accept decimal value of maximum two.  example 0.24,1.99 ,9.99 99.99 are valid result.  Invalid are 00.24, 000.25, 0.245, 999.000 are invalid

Answer (score 3):

If one assumes he really needs regexp - which is perfectly reasonable in many contexts - the problem is that the specific regexp variety needs to be specified. For example:

```
egrep '^(100|[1-9]|[1-9][0-9])$'
grep -E '^(100|[1-9]|[1-9][0-9])$'
```

work fine if the (...|...) alternative syntax is available.  In other contexts, they'd be backslashed like \(...\|...\)

Answer (score 3):

There are many options how to write a regex pattern for that

- `^(?:(?!0)\d{1,2}|100)$`
- `^(?:[1-9]\d?|100)$`
- `^(?!0)(?=100$|..$|.$)\d+$`

Answer (score 1):

I use for this angular 6

try this.

```
^([0-9]\.[0-9]{1}|[0-9]\.[0-9]{2}|\.[0-9]{2}|[1-9][0-9]\.[0-9]{1}|[1-9][0-9]\.[0-9]{2}|[0-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9]\.[0-9]{2})$|^([0-9]|[0-9][0-9]|[0-99])$|^100$
```

it's validate 0.00 - 100. with two decimal places.

hope this will help

```
<input matInput [(ngModel)]="commission" type="number" max="100" min="0" name="rateInput" pattern="^(\.[0-9]{2}|[0-9]\.[0-9]{2}|[0-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9]\.[0-9]{2})$|^([0-9]|[0-9][0-9]|[0-99])$|^100$" required #rateInput2="ngModel"><span>%</span><br>
```

Number should be between 0 and 100

Comment: more accurate one 

^([0-9]\.[0-9]{1}|[0-9]\.[0-9]{2}|\.[0-9]{2}|[1-9][0-9]\.[0-9]{1}|[1-9][0-9]\.[0-9]{2}|[0-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9]\.[0-9]{2})$|^([0-9]|[0-9][0-9]|[0-99])$|^100$

Comment: This works perfectly for me where the answer's expression allows for 3+ decimal places.

Answer (score 0):

Regular Expression for 0 to 100 with the decimal point.

```
^100(\.[0]{1,2})?|([0-9]|[1-9][0-9])(\.[0-9]{1,2})?$
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for the sake of delivering the shortest solution, here is mine:

`^([1-9]\d?|100)$`

[working fiddle](https://regex101.com/r/QsCLxZ/4/)

Answer (score 0):

1 - 1000 with leading 0's

```
/^0*(?:[1-9][0-9][0-9]?|[1-9]|1000)$/;
```

it should not accept `0`, `00`, `000`, `0000`.

it should accept `1`, `01`, `001`, `0001`

Answer (score 0):

The simplest one

```
^([1-9][0-9]?|100)$
```

**Edit**

The explanation detail
[1-9] matches between 1 and 9
[0-9]? is optional one between 0 and 9
| means OR
100 means 100

The combination matches between 1 and 100.

Comment: Explaining it would make it a better answer

Comment: Please add some explanation to your code rather than posting only code.

Answer (score -1):

between 0 and 100

```
/^(\d{1,2}|100)$/
```

or between 1 and 100

```
/^([1-9]{1,2}|100)$/
```

Comment: This isn't a very good answer. The first version matches 0, which the question says not to match. The second version doesn't match two-digit numbers.

Answer (score -6):

This is very simple logic, So no need of regx.

Instead go for using ternary operator

```
var num = 89;
var isValid = (num <=  100 && num > 0 ) ? true : false;
```

It will do the magic for you!!

Comment: Except for where you need a regex. For instance, say an xml template that is predefined, where the only way to limit input is by putting a regex in the template. Then there's no magic here.