# Regular Expression Number excluding 0

Tags: regex

I have to say I'm not very experienced in Reg. Expressions

Regex:

```
 ^[1-9]?[0-9]{1}$|^100$
```

I would like to test a number between 1 and 100, excluding 0

Comment: [Regex number between 1 and 100](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13473595/3110638)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this regex mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
^[1-9][0-9]?$|^100$
```

this is starting at a digit between 1 and 9

and ending at an optional 0 to 9 \

[**demo here**](http://regex101.com/r/rV3iV7)

Answer (score 1):

Try this regex:

```
^(?:[1-9]\d?|100)$
```

#### Description

[image: Regular expression visualization]

#### Demo

http://regex101.com/r/pU5cM6

Answer (score 0):

Following regex will match numbers>=1 and numbers<=100

```
^([1-9][0-9]?|100)$
```

Comment: This will match only 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, and 100, right?

Comment: Yes. it will match those numbers