# How do I figure out the percentage of elements in my array whose value is between 1 and 100?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby

I'm using Ruby 2.4.  I have a data array that has a bunch of strings ...

```
["a", "1", "123", "a2c", ...]
```

I can check the percentage of elements in my array that are exclusively numbers using

```
data_col.grep(/^\d+$/).size / data_col.size.to_f
```

but how do I check the percentage of elements taht are numbers and whose value falls between 1 and 100?

Comment: Do you have integers only or could there be floats?

Comment: There's always a regex: http://stackoverflow.com/q/13473523/477037 ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like

```
data_col.grep(/^\d+$/).count { |item| item.to_i.between?(1, 100) } / data_col.size.to_f
```

Comment: Hi, When my data_col is ["99a", "a", "", "25"], running the above returns 0.  Shoudn't it return ".25" since one of the elements in my array is a number?

Comment: Oh I'm sorry, I forgot to copy the ".to_f" at the end of your statement.

Comment: `item.to_i.between?(1, 100)` is even more descriptive.

Comment: Done. Thank you Stefan :)

Comment: The `grep(/^\d+$/)` part is actually unnecessary, because `to_i` always returns an integer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
1.0 * array.map(&:to_i).grep(1..100).size / array.size
```

How does this work?

- `grep` accepts any pattern that responds to `===`
- `Range#===` is defined as membership check

Comment: You can avoid `1.0 *` by using `fdiv` instead of `/`.