# how to get range of numbers in validation pattern

Tags: validation, angular, typescript

I want to validate numbers between 2009-2059 in validator pattern at typeScript code. I tried many ways but could not find a way to do it ? Could you please look at the sample code and tell me how to fix it ?

Regards
Alper

you can see the sample code below.

```
],'Input3': [this.guiTranformatorInput.JJJJ_input3,[
Validators.required,
 Validators.pattern('20[0-5][8-9]'),
  ]
```

Comment: Try use regex range of numbers as [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13473595/6097785)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your range pattern is wrong, try this

```
20((09)|([1-5][0-9]))

20: start with 20
(
09: literal 09
or
1-5 and 0-9
)
```

or using custom validator: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39848327/3676586

Comment: hello Tiep.Thanks for your help. . Is there any direct pattern for the values between min and max number at typeScript ?  I have to convert  between values into an algoirthm. If not , I will try to implement algorithm myself

Comment: thank you Tiep.I will try the sample. I think regex seems impossible when I try to implement between 2012-2078. That's really to hard to implement an algorithm. What do you think about it ?