# Regex number between

Tags: javascript

how to make regex for number from -100 to 100? Thanks in advance

Comment: Is there a reason you want to use regex and not simple comparison like x < 100 && x > -100 ?

Comment: [Regex number between 1 and 100](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13473523/regex-number-between-1-and-100) Maybe help you

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a regex range generator, such as http://gamon.webfactional.com/regexnumericrangegenerator/

I think this regular expression will do it:

```
/^-?([0-9]|[1-8][0-9]|9[0-9]|100)$/
```

Comment: `[1-8][0-9]|9[0-9]`?! That’s generators for you, I guess.

Answer (score -1):

use https://regex101.com/ for checking your regex.

and use `(?:\b|-)([1-9]{1,2}[0]?|100)\b` expression to print numbers from -100 to 100

Comment: Matches `990`, though.