# Pattern match check in Redshift

Tags: regex, amazon-redshift

One of my table column should have values as Concatenation of a percentage from 0 to 100 and one of the following values (R, MR, MS or S). Eg: `20MS`.

Should I use `REGEXP_COUNT` or `SIMILAR TO`, to check data validity.
Tried this but does not work:

```
SELECT REGEXP_COUNT('6A', '^[0-9]+(R|MR|MS|S)?')
```

Any suggestions or solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```sql
where column SIMILAR TO '[0-9]+(R|MR|MS|S)'
```

If the value after percentage is optional, use

```sql
where column SIMILAR TO '[0-9]+(R|MR|MS|S)?'
```

Using a regex operator `~` you can achieve

```sql
where column ~ '^[0-9]+(M?[RS])?$'
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/fMKWCY/1).

**Explanation**

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [0-9]+                   any character of: '0' to '9' (1 or more
                           times (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1 (optional
                           (matching the most amount possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    M?                       'M' (optional (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [RS]                     any character of: 'R', 'S'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )?                       end of \1 (NOTE: because you are using a
                           quantifier on this capture, only the LAST
                           repetition of the captured pattern will be
                           stored in \1)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of the
                           string
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution. This accepts any number, in the number part.
How can we validate the numeric part to be between 0 to 100.

Comment: @SatishTakkalapalli You can [take this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13473523/regex-number-between-1-and-100). `'^([1-9][0-9]?|100)(M?[RS])?$'`