# Is there a way for a regexp to match only strings with numbers higher than a particular, multiple digit value?

Tags: regex, integer

I know I can match numbers by doing something like `[2-9]` I would match only numbers 2 and higher, but what can I do for numbers with more digits?

For instance, if I wanted to match numbers higher than `734` I could do `[7-9][3-9][4-9]`, but that would not match some numbers like `741`.

Is there a proper way to do this? Also, can it be made to work for numbers with an arbitrarily large amount of digits?

Comment: Which language are you trying this in? Use the right tool for the job.

Comment: This is not what regex is intended for. You would have to describe "larger as 734" as a pattern, this is complicated and error prone, see e.g. [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/676467/how-to-match-numbers-between-x-and-y-with-regexp?rq=1) as an example. Match all numbers and use the normal operators to check if the the number is larger, smaller, ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to spell out all the possible *textual* representation of allowed numbers. This is not what regexes are good at - it will work, but it's definitely hard to maintain/change:

```
^(73[4-9]|7[4-9]\d|[89]\d\d|\d{4,})$
```

matches all numbers from `734` and up.

See it [live on regex101.com](http://regex101.com/r/gT9lC8).

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't do this with just a regex.  If you are trying to do this from within a program or script, you should use a regex to extract the digits then try to parse it as a number.

Alternatively, if you are simply just trying to process a file and don't care how it's done there are various tools which can do it for you.

Comment: Of course you *can*  do it with a regex. I'm not saying that you *should*, though.

Comment: I should probably have said you can't _practically_ do it with a regex.  I took the OP to be asking whether there was a regex syntax to do this in a straightforward manner rather constructing massively complicated expressions. :-)

Answer (score -1):

Use number of digits found in your input

may be you have 'n' numbers in your input

n=4 
input = 1234; or number = 8704

So,
 you can use

```
[0-9]{4}
```

Or 
Some time you need to match the Digits must be at least above 2 means

```
[2-9]{4}
```

May be i have Digits of 4 or 5

```
[2-9]{4,5}
```

**Its match**

8567

94877

**But Not match**

2

999999999

7937827857

Comment: I don't know how this answers the question, but in general, if you want to match exactly 4 digits with `[0-9]{4}` you need to use anchors, otherwise this would also match "1234" in "1234567".