# What is the precise Regex in google form for whole number greater than 6 with no leading zero?

Tags: javascript, regex

The closest I found after trying all the various answers in earlier similar question was below:-

```
^[6-9]|[0-9]\d+$
```

but this still allows the leading zeros. Any help to restrict the leading zeros as well, please?

The answer suggested in [How to match numbers between X and Y with regexp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/676467/how-to-match-numbers-between-x-and-y-with-regexp) is not my solution because it still allows numbers below 6.

Comment: _“but this still allows the leading zeros”_ — Your second alternative states `[0-9]`; I wouldn’t expect otherwise. `[0-9]` means any digit from 0 to 9. You need the one from 1 to 9.

Comment: Thanks,@user4642212! Your answer definitely a solution I've looked for the whole night last night!

Comment: that one still allows numbers below 6, @ggorlen.

Comment: I think you're taking the dupe target a bit too literally--it's not feasible for there to be a different post for how to write a regex to match every possible number or range. The way to go is to learn the general technique for matching numbers with regex from the canonical thread and apply it to your specific case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one to avoid leading zero:

```
^(?:[6-9]|[1-9]\d+)$
```

Comment: yep, this one is the precise answer, @Robo Robok! Because unlike my earlier amended regex, this one immediately punches not match pattern when I entered the negative values. Thanks a lot!