# Regular expression to match number entered is in between -50 to 100000000

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to write a regular expression which can match enter number string which should be in range of
`-50 to 100000000`

*I have tried expression like*

`^(-?)(1000|[0-9][0-9][0-9]?)$`

but it matches only -1000 to 1000 numbers.

example for to test are simple

```
-50
-39
9
1000
36900
2000022
```

Please help me to get such expression which can be match range -50 to 100M

I know we can write simple if condition but I want regex only.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Are you using pcre or javascript?

Comment: That's... not what Regex are for... "I know we can write simple if condition but I want regex only." - WHY?!

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/676467/how-to-match-numbers-between-x-and-y-with-regexp

Comment: The minus sign should only be applicable to the -50 till -1 part and not for the whole expression. `^(?:-0*(?:[1-9]|[1-4][0-9]|50)|(?:0*[0-9]{1,8}|100000000))$`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the following regex:

```
/^(-50|-[1-4]?\d|100000000|[1-9]?\d{1,7})$/gm
```

**Explanation**:

`^` match start of string

`-50` match -50

OR

`-` only negative numbers

`[1-4]?` match 1 to 4 - optional, followed by: any number

OR

`100000000` match 100000000

OR

`[1-9]?` match 1 to 9 - optional followed by:

`\d{1,7}` match any number 1 to 7 times

`$` match end of line

Use `global` and `multiline` options.

Comment: that would be great if you add solution if user add fractional value 33.44 upto 2 decimal places.

Comment: That's not what the OP wants, so no.

Comment: searching similar kind of answer with 2 decimal places can you please suggest.

Comment: Ok, try this: `^(-50|-[1-4]?\d(\.\d\d?)?|100000000|[1-9]?\d{1,7}(\.\d\d?)?)$` - that will allow one or two decimals.

Comment: ^(-50|-[1-4]?\d(\.\d\d?)?|100000000|[1-9]?\d{1,7}(\.\d\d?)?)$ this expression works fine but boundary point not accept 50.00 or 100000000.00 can you please suggest.

Comment: @Nikse: Add `(\.00?)?` after `-50` and after `100000000`

Comment: Thank you it works as expected.

Answer (score 3):

Regular expression serving leading zeros and positive and negative sign. Works only for integers.

```
^(-0*(50|[0-4]?[0-9])|\+?0*([0-9]{1,8}|100000000))$
```

Test case

[image: Test case]

Using with JavaScript:

```
let number = -50; /* <-- test number or string here */
let withinTheRange = Boolean(/^(-0*(50|[0-4]?[0-9])|\+?0*([0-9]{1,8}|100000000))$/.exec(number));
```

Comment: That's a complete solution. Great work!