# Regex Number Validation

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a number that is not accepted to be negative or empty/null or number and not be decimal and between 1 to 40

**example:**

> 0  not match
> -1 not match
> 1  match
> 41 not match
> 1.1 not match
> null not match

**this code is not Work**

```
\b(-\d+?0?[1-9]|[1-3][0-9]|4[0])\b
```

Comment: Int number range from `1` to `40` regex - `^(?:[1-9]|[1-3][0-9]|40)$`. Check out [this generator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67502416/3832970).

Comment: if you are using an input field for the number make it type="number" and set min,max and step accordingly