# Filter with grep a value greater and less than range

Tags: filter, grep

I have a csv with this data:

```
0,M,19,finnish,english swedish german 
9,M,30,urdu,english 
122,F,26,finnish,english swedish german
83,M,20,finnish,english french swedish 
44,F,20,finnish,english swedish 
10,F,29,finnish,english
```

And I need a filter using GREP than take user value (first column) great than 10 and less than 99.

This is my best movement:

```
cat demographic_info.csv | grep -e "1[0-9]*"
```

Comment: grep does not understand numeric values. It only understands text patterns.  It does not understand the idea of "greater than 10".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you want to match numbers from `10` to `99` exclusively (that is, `11` to `98` inclusively), you can use

```sh
grep -E '^(1[1-9]|[2-8][0-9]|9[0-8]),' file
```

The numeric range pattern is automatically generated at [How to match numbers between X and Y with regexp?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67502416/3832970), I just needed to remove `?:` as POSIX ERE does not support non-capturing groups.

However,

```sh
awk -F\, '$1 < 99 && $1 > 10' file
```

looks a much better fit for this task. It uses a comma as a field separator, and checks if the first field value is less than 99 and bigger than 10, and outputs only those lines.

See an [online demo](https://ideone.com/36iaNm):

```sh
#!/bin/bash
s='0,M,19,finnish,english swedish german 
9,M,30,urdu,english 
122,F,26,finnish,english swedish german
83,M,20,finnish,english french swedish 
44,F,20,finnish,english swedish 
10,F,29,finnish,english'
awk -F\, '$1 < 99 && $1 > 10' <<< "$s"
echo "---"
grep -E '^(1[1-9]|[2-8][0-9]|9[0-8]),' <<< "$s"
```

Output:

```
83,M,20,finnish,english french swedish 
44,F,20,finnish,english swedish 
---
83,M,20,finnish,english french swedish 
44,F,20,finnish,english swedish
```

Comment: Hi Wiktor Stribiżew 

Thanks for your help. 

That true, with awk it's easier but I had to do with GREP and really I didn't know how to did.