# How can I search a specific numbers in between two numbers ? On notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I’m new on Notepad++ and I want to know how can I lookup for a numbers in between two numbers:

Like I want to search in a text file full of numbers and words, and I only want to find the numbers between 250-500; so, all the numbers from 250-500 will be in search, in others words, no numbers should be search but only the number between 250-500!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has nothing to do with programming.

Comment: `\b(?:2[5-9]\d|[34]\d\d|500)\b`

Comment: @RamblinRose: Well, you know, Notepad++ questions are welcome at SO.

Comment: @Toto point taken, I didn't realize it even had a tag, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>
- Find what: `\b(?:2[5-9]\d|[34]\d\d|500)\b`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Find All in Current Document</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
\b              # word boundary
(?:             # non capture group
    2[5-9]\d        # matches 250 upto 299
  |               # OR
    [34]\d\d        # 300 upto 499
  |               # OR
    500             # 500
)               # end group
\b              # word boundary
```

**Screenshot[image]:**

Comment: Also, one can use the snippet given in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67502416/11613622) to quickly generate the regex for any range.