# Regular expression for accepting integers, decimal values and limiting by maximum value

Tags: regex, integer, range, decimal

I need a regular expression that accept only integers or decimals from 1 to 9999.99. I tried this

```
^(?:[1-9][0-9]{0,4}(?:.d{1,2})?|9999|9999.99)$
```

but it is also accepting 10000.

Comment: It's also *not* accepting `999.99`.

Comment: ok..Any help is appreciated

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but this expression is not accepting all 2 digit, 3 digit, 4 digit numbers.

Comment: @Rakhi As per the examples shared in the demo link, it does match 1/2/3/4 digit nos

Comment: Are you using a specific programming language? Arithmetic is usually a much better solution.

Comment: I am using it for yup validation using .match

Comment: You can [generate any numeric range regex here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67502416/3832970). Anyway, `d` can never match a digit, `\d` matches a digit. Also, `.` matches any char other than line break chars, a `\.` matches a dot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a few issues in the pattern:

- This part `[1-9][0-9]{0,4}` can match 1-5 digits as the quantifier is 0-4 times so it can match 10000 as well
- You don't need `9999|9999.99` as those can already be matched by `1-9][0-9]{0,4}`
- This part `.d` matches any char except a newline followed by a `d` char. You have to escape both to match a dot literally and a single digit
- With those changes, you can omit the outer capture group

The updated pattern looks like:

```
^[1-9]\d{0,3}(?:\.\d{1,2})?$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `[1-9]\d{0,3}` Match a single digit 1-9 and repeat 0 to 3 times a digit 0-9
- `(?:\.\d{1,2})?` Optionally match a `.` and 1 or 2 digits
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/6dwW6Z/1)

Comment: This **is** the right answer. I started regex101'ing before reading the answers and my regex turned out identical to yours.

Answer (score 2):

Try this regex:

```
^0*(?!\.\d+)[1-9]\d{0,3}(?:\.\d{1,2})?$
```

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/RbvAgT/1)**

**Explanation:**

- `^` - matches start of the string
- `0*` - matches 0+ occurrences of digit `0`
- `(?!\.\d+)` - zero-length match if the current position is not followed by a `.` and 1+ digits
- `[1-9]` - matches a digit from 1 to 9
- `\d{0,3}` - matches at-least 0 or at-most 3 occurences of a digit
- `(?:\.\d{1,2})?` - matches the decimal `.` followed by 1 or 2 digits. A `?` at the end to make the fractional part optional
- `$` - matches the end of string

Comment: Thank you. This regex not supporting 22, 33, 434 etc..supports only when adding 0 before each number. Help is appreciated

Comment: [Sorry, but it does match the values you have mentioned](https://regex101.com/r/oQYglx/1)

Comment: I'm not sure why you put the `0*(?!\.\d+)`. And if you remove this, it's almost identical with the other answer, but still a bit earlier it seems.

Comment: @bobblebubble I had added `0*` to match inputs like `01`,`001`,`00001`. I had added `(?!\.\d+)` so as to exclude inputs like `.99`, `.11` as the OP had asked to include the numbers>=1

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply! Well, not clear about that, however upvoted for it already.

Answer (score 1):

Another idea but there is not much difference regarding performance (just for fun).

```
^(?!0)\d{1,4}(?:\.\d\d?)?$
```

The *looakhead* `(?!0)` prevents starting with zero, so we can further match `\d{1,4}`.

Does not respect leading zeros. [See this demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/vF7XpA/1).