# regex to match specific set of numbers or letters

Tags: r, regex, regex-group, stringr

Working with survey data classified into various "waves", with each wave labeled either 1 - 14, or the letters "A" or "E", followed by the variable name.

For example, want to parse:

- 3educ > wave: 3, variable: educ
- Aage > wave: A, variable: age

Tried various strings, such as

```
^([0-9]?|A|E)(\\w+)
```

to no effect. Please advise.

(Using stringr with R)

Comment: Based on your input strings, you can consider this regex [`\b([1-9]|1[0-4]|[AE])([a-z]+)\b`](https://regex101.com/r/QHKr6d/1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to create a regex for a numeric range, consider using the [automatic numeric range regex generator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67502416/3832970). The regex to match integer numbers from `1` to `14` is `(?:[1-9]|1[0-4])`.

So, you need to use

```r
(?i)^(?P<wave>[1-9AE]|1[0-4])(?P<variable>\w+)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/4zF82S/4). `(?i)` sets the case insensitive mode on and `[1-9AE]` matches either a non-zero digit or `A` or `E` chars.

In R, you can use named capturing groups with [`namedCapture` library](https://github.com/tdhock/namedCapture):

```r
x <- c("3educ","Aage","14abc","Ekajshklasjf")
library(namedCapture)
str_match_all_named(x, "(?i)^(?<wave>[1-9AE]|1[0-4])(?<variable>\\w+)")
```

Output:

```
[[1]]
     wave variable
[1,] "3"  "educ"  

[[2]]
     wave variable
[1,] "A"  "age"   

[[3]]
     wave variable
[1,] "1"  "4abc"  

[[4]]
     wave variable     
[1,] "E"  "kajshklasjf
```

Comment: Very useful, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind I think I got it:

```
^([0-9][0-9]?|a|e)(\\w+)
```

Comment: you regex will also select `15educ`i.e.,  numbersvare not restricted from 1 to 14. Moreover, [0-9] and `\w` are not mutually-exclusive.

Comment: That's ok, as only 1-14 are present.