# Regex for numbers - how to bucket / group the values

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group

I would like to create Regex for the values like this:

0 – 3000

3001 -5000

5001 -10000

10001 – 30000

30001 – 50000

50001 – max

Can any one help me on this how to create regex.

Thanks all

Comment: If you're using a programming language, then it would probably better to just do range inequality checks using variables, rather than pure regex.

Comment: Regexes don't know about numeric values. It just finds string patterns. This is not a task for a regex.

Comment: found a Regex Numeric Range Generator URL  https://3widgets.com/  i think it will be helpful for all.

Comment: [Here is a number range regex generator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67502416/3832970) on SO.