# regex less than 230000

Tags: regex

I am trying to get value less than `230001` in list **and** two number after space 20 or 10 **and** Last character is `X`. I tried:

```
[0-2][0-3][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] (20|10) X
```

```
-z001 230001 20 X
-z011  26321 10 *
-z002 230000 10 X
-z003 134242 12 *
-z004 199999 10 X
-z005 299999 20 X
```

My expected result is

```
-z002 230000 10 X
-z004 199999 10 X
```

Comment: You should do this check using an inequality comparison from your code if possible.

Comment: Regext are not fit for this kind of problem

Comment: What's your context? If you're trying to grep files, you could get the 20 or 10 and the X, then sort the rest or do some AWK or similar... Or are you doing this in code somewhere?

Comment: Why is `-z005 299999 20 X` an expected result? To me `299999` is higher than `230000`. Have a look at [this](https://regex101.com/r/gTAbqU/1)

Comment: I mean my expect result is 
-z002 230000 10 X
-z004 199999 10 X

sorry but i dont know how to edit this post :D

Comment: you just have to list all the possibilities - https://regex101.com/r/mu3yYM/1 - but as other people have said, a simple numerical comparison would be better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
.* ([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]{1,4}|1[0-9]{5}|2[0-2][0-9]{4}|230000) [12]0 X.*
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/SKzzLn/2).

The numeric range regex is generated with this [numeric range regex generator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67502416/3832970).

*Details*:

- `.*` - any zero or more chars as many as possible
- - space
- `([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]{1,4}|1[0-9]{5}|2[0-2][0-9]{4}|230000)` - `0` to `23000` number regex
- - space
- `[12]0` - `1` or `2` and then `0`
- `X` - space, `X`
- `.*` - any zero or more chars as many as possible.