# Match a Particular set of string with regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to match a particular set of strings with a regex

1- **#1 – .75 Gallon $16.99**

2- **#2 –1.6 Gallon $36.99**

This is what I tried to figure out with many attempts but still it doesn't seems to work

```js
console.log(/^#\d\s+–\s+[0-9]*\.[0-9]+\s+[a-zA-Z]+\s+:[0-9]*\.[0-9]+$/.test('#2 – 1.6 Gallon $36.99'))

console.log(/^#\d\s+–\s+[0-9]*\.[0-9]+\s+[a-zA-Z]+\s+:[0-9]*\.[0-9]+$/.test('#1 – .75 Gallon $16.99'))
```

I have gone through each part individually but I don't know where I am making mistake ,any help would be really appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: You have `:` instead of `\$`. Use `^#\d\s*–\s*[0-9]*\.[0-9]+\s+[a-zA-Z]+\s+\$[0-9]*\.[0-9]+$`

Comment: What is the expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should allow *any* (even zero) amount of whitespaces around the hyphen, and you need to match a dollar symbol instead of a colon:

```
^#\d\s*–\s*\d*\.?\d+\s+[a-zA-Z]+\s+\$\d*\.?\d+$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/XVGsjJ/2).

I also added a `?` quantifier after `\.` to match integers.

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `#` - a `#` char
- `\d` - a digit
- `\s*–\s*` - a hyphen wrapped with zero or more whitespaces
- `\d*\.?\d+` - an integer or float like value: zero or more digits, an optional `.` and then one or more digits
- `\s+` - one or more whitespaces
- `[a-zA-Z]+` - one or more letters
- `\s+` - one or more whitespaces
- `\$` - a `$` char
- `\d*\.?\d+` - an integer or float like value
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: Thanks a lot :) ,just one small thing i don't want the value $16.99 ,the value after $ to not  be greater than 1000 ,how can i do that .please if you can tell.

Comment: You will need to replace `\d*\.?\d+` with `(?:\d|[1-9]\d{1,2})(?:\.\d+)?`. This matches a number from `0` to `999` (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67502416/3832970) how to generate such patterns).