# Regular Expression for IPv4 subnet

Tags: regex, kql, ipv4, subnet

I am trying to create a regular expression for the IP subnet 192.168.224.0/22. The valid IP range is 192.168.224.1 to 192.168.227.254.

I can use this in Sentinel KQL query. Is the below correct?

```
192\.168\.(22[4-7]|23[0-6])\.(25[0-4]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)
```

Comment: try: `^192\.(?:1[6-9]|[2-9][0-9]|1[0-5][0-9]|16[0-8])\.22[4-7]\.(?:[1-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-4])$` see:https://regex101.com/r/IibgVH/latest.
You will need to excape the literal `.`. For defining numeric ranges also see:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/676467/how-to-match-numbers-between-x-and-y-with-regexp/67502416#67502416

Comment: Do you have to say everything twice? Do you have to say everything twice?

Comment: No. For a start, you're allowing the third octet to be 230-236

Comment: Also, here is a [IP Range Regular Expression Builder](https://www.analyticsmarket.com/freetools/ipregex)